# How to solve this degree $2N$ polynomial equation of filter's cut-off frequency?

Tags: filters, bandwidth, differential-equation

In a paper I am interested in, the following equation is given to determine the cut-off frequency $\omega$ of a filter:

$$t^{2N}+\left[-2\left(1-\frac{1}{2Q^2}\right)\right]t^N +\left[-\left(\frac{|H(\omega_{CF})|}{\gamma \, \omega_0^{2N-1}}\right)^{-\frac{2}{N}}\right] t +\omega_0^4  =0$$
Where $t=\omega^{\frac{2}{N}}$, $Q$ is the quality factor, $N$ is the filter order, $\omega_0$ is the natural frequency, $|H(\omega_{CF})|$ is the filter peak-gain and $\gamma=\sqrt{2}$ for the response at -3dB.

Since only $\omega$ is unknown, I can see that the equation has the form $x^{2N}a +  x^{N}b + xc +d$. However, I am failing to understand how $\omega$ can be evaluated.
In addition, is it possible to find the value of $Q$ for any given $\omega$.

Thank you for helping with this.

Comment: Numeric methods?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#Roots_of_polynomials

Comment: That's an awkward equation. Not sure what a "typical" filter order is, but you end up with $2N+1$ solutions, most of which will probably be complex.

Comment: @Hilmar In that case only one will be real, so maybe that's the one? But if $t=\omega^{2/N}$ then $t^{2N}=\omega^{2N\cdot 2/N}=\omega^4$, all the time, irrespective of $N$, similar for $t^N$, while $t=\omega^{2/N}$. If $N>2$ it ends up fractional. The plot thickens.

Answer (score 1):

> Since only $\omega$ is unknown, I can see that the equation has the form $x^{2N}a +  x^{N}b + xc +d$.

Exactly, you're looking for the roots (i.e., points where the value is 0) of a polynomial in $t$. The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra tells us that this polynomial has $2N$ roots, some of which might have *multiplicity* > 1 (so potentially, there's fewer *different* roots).

Although I *think* it's possible to find an elegant *factorization* of this polynomial by guessing one root, numerical methods for such problems abound. Your favourite math tool (Python, Julia, MATLAB or Mathematica, or whatever!) certainly comes with a root-finding toolbox as well.

> However, I am failing to understand how $\omega$ can be evaluated.

1. Find all $t_k$ solving the equation
2. For each of these $t_k$, find all $\omega_{k,\ell}$ such that $t_k=\omega_{k,\ell}^{\frac{2}{N}}$. (Note: of course, $\omega_{·,·}=\sqrt[N]{t_k}^2$ if it exists is one solution, but so might $-\sqrt[N]{t_k}^2$ etc.)

I'm *guessing* that all possible $\omega$ necessarily are real, so that you can throw away a lot of potential solutions here. This might mean that you might already only be interested in real $t_k$, so that [numerically searching for real roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation) might be a good approach if $N$ is very large. (Otherwise, your computer will spend most of its time computing irrelevant imaginary roots.)

> In addition, is it possible to find the value of $Q$ for any given $\omega$.

Sure, just rearranging your original equations so that $Q^2$ stands alone, but there's going to be two solutions.

---

Personally: sit down, write down the polynomial in $t$ as polynomial in $\omega$, then implement it for a "reasonable example" selection of $Q$, $N$ and $\omega_0$, and plot it in real, imaginary part and absolute value. Might give you a bit of an intuition. It's not a very intuitive formula, as unconstrained as shown, for something as real as a cutoff frequency.

I'd also look for what the authors of your paper *do* with that equation. Maybe they implicitly give a hint.

Comment: Yes, the solution should be real. I have been trying with mathlab but it didn't find any root. So I'm basically trying to solve a degree 3 polynomial equation here? what puzzles me is what should I do with the power $^{2N}$ and $^N$. How can I put it in the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$?

Comment: no, you're trying to solve a degree $2N$ polynomial equation. As said (in breadth!), any such equation has $2N$ solutions, no exceptions. However, as said, not all of these solution must be different; ther is not any guarantee there's a real solution, even.

Comment: for example, the equation $x^{2N}+1 = 0$ definitely has $2N$ solutions, but definitely no real one.